# Empty interface or empty base class to use as type parameter constraint

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-parameter, type-constraints

Suppose I have a generic class in C# whose declaration looks like this:

```
public abstract class DtoQuery<T> where T : class
{ }
```

Now, the type parameter is intended to always be a "Dto" class. I have a bunch of these, but the "problem" is that they have *nothing* in common. They all have just a bunch of (distinct) public properties and no methods.

Ideally I would like to make my `DtoQuery<T>` class accept only such "Dto" classes as its type parameter. So I would either need to create an empty interface `IDto` or an empty `abstract class Dto`.

Question: which one should I go with? Note: the Dto classes will never extend anything else or each other!

(P.S. for the curious: I promise I'm not building something extremely stupid and silly, this is utility functionality in a testing project and won't be used for production code).

Comment: Since it's to be empty anyways, I'd go for the interface. But since it's not important to you (according to your P.S.) and will have no consequences, why do you ask at all? This is not even opinion based, simply roll a dice :)

Comment: @RenéVogt I'm asking because the fact that I don't know a reason why it makes a difference, doesn't mean no one else in the community might know a reason. That's what questions are for, aren't they :)? Also, what if this *was* a production code situation?

Comment: What *code* can you write when the generic type you're dealing with has no methods or properties?

Comment: If both an interface and abstract class can accomplish the same thing, pick the interface. Two reasons: 1. An abstract class is *only* useful when you need implementation (which is not true if either option is possible). 2. You can implement many interfaces, but only inherit from one class. Inheriting from this abstract class limits your options in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have (for whatever reason), a hierarchy that looks like this:

```
public class Person { }
public class Employee : Person { }
public class Boss : Person { }
```

Now imagine, that we don't want a `Person` to be treated as a DTO - we only want Employee and Boss to be DTOs.

In this situation, it would be impossible to use an abstract class to denote a DTO, as you can only inherit from one parent in C#.

That's an objective reason as to why using an interface is better. Subjectively, interfaces are also better because the purpose of an abstract class is to provide some functionality. Other than that, is has no benefit over an interface.

The rule of thumb is: Always use an interface when you're unsure. Only use an abstract class if you *need* implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Rob's answer, but since you mentioned that "the Dto classes will never extend anything else or each other" I'm going to add another reason that might tip you towards an interface:

If you choose an interface, you can keep it internal. A public class can implement an internal interface, but it cannot extend an internal class. That also means that consumers of your library wouldn't be able to create new DTO types using the same abstract base class.

You also mentioned that this is going to be used in a test project, so you can use the `[assembly: InternalsVisibleToAttribute("Name.Of.Test.Project")]` attribute to expose it to only your testing assembly.